# Telegram Bot Keyboard Button

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I got problem with Telegram Keyboard , I want to send a string in my array for markup that has a "#"
but with "#" it dosent work
and I visited a bot that same mine and that's works good and shows '#' in Keyboard Button

how can I fix this??

```
$string = "#number 1";//This # 

$markup[] = [
    ["text" =>  $string ]
];

$keyboard = [
    "keyboard" => $markup,
    "resize_keyboard" => true
];

return $r = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot" . TOKEN . "/sendMessage?chat_id="
    . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("MENU") . "&reply_markup=" . json_encode($keyboard));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` will interfere with the request url.

You should escape it to prevent this.

Easiest solution is to use [php](/questions/tagged/php)'s [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function on the text thats containing any special chars:

```php
<?php

    $chat_id = ;
    CONST TOKEN = '';

    $keyboard = [
        "keyboard" => [
            [
                ["text" =>  urlencode('Test -> #') ]
            ]
        ],
        "resize_keyboard" => true
    ];

    return file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot" . TOKEN . "/sendMessage?chat_id="
        . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("MENU") . "&reply_markup=" . json_encode($keyboard));
```

Will produce:

[image]